# Azure AutoShutdown with timer, but no user connected

Tags: azure, shutdown

I have a VM in Azure and want to shut it down (stop-deallocated) after 23:00 but only if no users are logged on.

I already have 2 runbooks to start (08:00) and stop (23:00)

Can I make a rule to only run the runbook to shutdown if no users are logged on?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, but the only way to do that is connect to the vm and query if it has active user sessions with `quser` or something like that. Azure doesnt know what happens inside your VM, so there is no platform level API you can query to get this data.

this also creates a problem of connectivity, in short I'd just shut vm's down at 23.00. there is absolutely zero benefit in what you are trying to achieve, but it is very hard to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs this,

I've created a powershell command inside the VM that counts how many users are connected via VPN (OpenVPN) and schedule it to run at 23:00, repeating every 15 minutes.
That way, if a user is connected, the VM does not shutdown.

This way, I can save € by shutting down the VM during the night, but no one will be forced out at 23h.